# Unable to align Left, Middle and Right with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, alignment

[image]

Unable to align Left, Middle and Right based on DIV.
I need a simple layout as i posted in image.

When i am trying to make right alignment it getting fully messed up.

can you please check and help me to get the layout i want.

My code :

```css
   body {
                background: #000000 50% 50%;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }
            
            .video {
width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;                
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
            }
            
            .left {
                
            text-align: left;
            position: absolute;
            }
            .right {
            text-align: right;
            position: absolute;
            }
```

```html
<body>

<div class="left">
    <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/336x280" /> <br>
  <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/280x500" />
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="video">
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/500x500" />

    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
    <p style="color: blue;">title</p>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/336x280" /> <br>
  <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/280x500" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  background: #000000 50% 50%;
}

.video {
  margin: 50px 20px;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">


    <div class="left">
        <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
        <img src="https://place-hold.it/336x280" /> <br>
        <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
        <img src="https://place-hold.it/280x500" />
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="video">
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/500x500" />

    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <p style="color: blue;">title</p>
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/336x280" /> <br>
      <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/280x500" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this works!!. But the Video DIV is not vertical center.

Comment: and how to make this responsive